# How to troubleshoot Django registration error

Tags: django, authentication, django-views, registration, user-registration

I'm encountering an issue with the registration functionality in my Django project. When I attempt to register a new user, I receive a generic error message, "There was an error, please try again," instead of a successful registration confirmation.

Here is my project view.py

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ("You Have Been Logged In!"))
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ("There was an error, please try again"))
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})

def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, ("You have been logged out"))
    return redirect('home')
```

pages navbar.html

```
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
```

pages urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That error is here ``` messages.success(request, ("There was an error, please try again"))```  What does your ```authenticate``` function do?  If it authenticates only, then users aren't being registered.  As I understand your code, you're checking if the user is not None.  If ```user``` is None, it means the user doesn't in your users base.

Comment: @ewokx Thank you so much for your helpful feedback! I'm still a bit uncertain about the next steps for troubleshooting the error. Could you please offer some further guidance on specific areas I should focus on?

Comment: Next steps would be to: (a) ensure that the username and password are being supplied to the auth function correctly; (b) check that the user exists in the database; (c) resetting the user's password in the database.